# подмена referer в новом окне при переходе по ссылке

Tags: javascript, html

Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Go(Obj) {

 Obj.innerHTML=(Obj.innerHTML=='Добавить в друзья')? 'Добавить в друзья': 'Открыть еще раз';

}

</script>
```

И есть вот такой html код:

```
<a href='https://vk.com/id$Row[uidvk]' target='_blank'  onclick='Go(this); '><font color='2B587A'>Добавить в друзья</font></a>
```

В данный момент есть кнопка Добавить в друзья, по нажатию на неё открывается новая вкладка, а надпись на кнопке меняется на Открыть ещё раз.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать что-бы всё работало точно так же, но что-бы была подмена referer для того что-бы Вк ничего не узнал.

Comment: Подмена когда на что? Вопрос непонятен

Comment: `X?Y:Y`... Какая иллюзия выбора.

Comment: @D-side, тут еще интереснее - условие всегда `false` :-)

Comment: да на любой другой сайт, мол из гугла например пришел

Comment: честно говоря так и не понятно чего вы хотите. Что за подмена такая, что вы творите, что за чудесные махинации хотите сделать........ может быть вам нужно Vk API?

Comment: нет) просто хочу при переходе с сайта своего на вк, что-бы вк думал, что это ч гугла переход, а не с сайта моего.

Comment: для чего? что за цель странная? что-то мне кажется вы какую-то задачу пытаетесь сделать странными способами

Comment: как зачем, что-бы нельзя было отследить откуда пришел пользователь. чтоб показывало. что пришли люди с гугла например, а не с сайта моего. массово это будет, сайт накрутк друзей. что тут странного? как заменить referer при переходе по ссылке?

Answer (score 3):

**Подменить** — никак, в браузерах это не реализовано.

Но можно **убрать**. Любым из перечисленных способов:

- В `<head>` добавить `<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />`: тогда браузер не будет раскрывать, "откуда пришёл" по всем ссылкам и запросам из JS на странице.
- Атрибут `rel="noreferrer"` у конкретной ссылки.
- Страница по HTTPS, ссылка на HTTP: браузер не будет раскрывать по небезопасному соединению, где он был по безопасному.
- *(Высокоградусный костыль)* Замаскировать в `data`-URL, содержащем HTML-страницу с `<meta>`-перенаправлением. Реферрером в этом случае будет этот самый `data`-URL и раскрытия не произойдёт.

---

Подробнее:

- [W3C Referrer Policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/)
- [Security.SE: "Playing with Referrer header"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/playing-with-referrer-header)